# Yii determining existence of related models

Tags: web-applications, activerecord, yii, findall

I want to run a findAll query that that only returns records where a related record doesn't exist.

Can anyone tell me how this is done in Yii?

Just a little bit of context in case it helps-

I'm working on a survey application, the objects I'm working with are-

QuestionSurvey
AnsweredQuestion

SurveyQuestion HAS_MANY AnsweredQuestion

I therefore want to return QuestionSurvey models where no related AnsweredQuestion exists.

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `SurveyQuestion::model()->with('AnsweredQuestion')->findAll()` this will happen automatically. Because it will pull all the records down together joined by an `INNER JOIN` (unless you tell it otherwise) and it will therefore not pull any questions down if they have no answers.

...I think.

**Update**
OK from your comments, I got it wrapped around my head. You actually want to view all the `SurveyQuestions` where `AnsweredQuestions` don't exist for it. In which case you want Yii to perform a `LEFT JOIN` which will pull down a NULL record for the joined table if a row doesn't exists. Then you need to add a condition to the relationship which states where `AnsweredQuestion.id is NULL` (Or whatever your primary key is, actually can be any field but primary key is good practice).

If this is a single instance kind of thing as opposed to a more permanent relationship then you can do:

```
SurveyQuestion::model()->with(array(
    'AnsweredQuestion'=>array(
        'joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN', 
        'condition'=>'`AnsweredQuestion`.`id` is NULL')
    )->findAll();
```

Comment: That's not quite what I mean. The AnsweredQuestion model is meant to indicate what questions have already been answered. Therefore if there is a related record, I don't want the parent record included. I think this is the reverse of what you're saying. Would you know how to reverse what Yii does naturally?

Comment: Not quite. AnsweredQuestions doesn't hold the answers, it just lists what has already been answered. I want to get hold of a list of SurveyQuestion's that don't have any related AnsweredQuestion's. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was what I was looking for. It's thrown up another question about only returning records related to the user, in case you're interested- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211257/yii-correct-syntax-for-conditions-in-relation-definitions

Comment: According to the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRelation#joinType-detail) `with` defaults to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, all records with/or without the relation will be gathered!