# Yii correct syntax for conditions in relation definitions

Tags: web-applications, yii, relation

I'm struggling to get the correct syntax for a relation condition I'm trying to set. The main relation is set with the foreign key question_id, but also contained in the child table is the user_id column.

I wish to return only records related to the logged in user. Here's what I've got so far-

```
  class SurveyQuestion extends CActiveRecord {
 .......

   public function relations()
    {
        return array(           
            'answered_questions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'AnsweredQuestion', 'question_id',
                'condition'=>"answered_questions.user_id = Yii::app()->user->id'"),
        );
   }
```

Please can someone correct my syntax which is so far not working? I've not been working with Yii for very long and so I wouldn't be surprised if my 'condition' clause was all wrong.

Many thanks,

Nick

Comment: not sure if this is the only problem, but `"answered_questions.user_id = Yii::app()->user->id'"` has a rogue quote at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`answered_questions.user_id = Yii::app()->user->id'` will check if answered_questions.user_id is equal to the string 'Yii:: .....' Not the actual user ID. You need to end the quote and append it as a PHP command:

`'condition'=>"answered_questions.user_id = ".Yii::app()->user->id),`

Unless this was a typo only in your question?

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't a typo and this answers my question. It's thrown something else up, but I'll post that in another question. Cheers!

Comment: Here's the follow on question, incase you're interested- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212084/yii-query-returning-no-results