# Yii query returning no results

Tags: web-applications, yii, findall

I'm struggling to create the correct query in Yii, I believe I'm making progress though.

I need to check a related table and only want to return records that don't have a record in the related table. This was answered here- [Yii determining existence of related models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210492/yii-determining-existence-of-related-models/13210522#comment17988445_13210522)

What is complicating this and I'm unsure how to overcome it, is that multiple users can have records in this related table. Therefore the full requirement is to return records where no related record exists, but only counting records for the logged in users.

The two related objects are as follows-
SurveyQuestion
AnsweredQuestion

SurveyQuestion HAS_MANY AnsweredQuestion

AnsweredQuestion table has the following columns-

id - survey_question_id - user_id

survey_question_id is the foreign key for the SurveyQuestion table.

My approach so far is to try and limit the records to those relevant to the logged in user with the relation definition-

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'survey_answer'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'SurveyAnswer','survey_question_id'),
        'answered_questions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'AnsweredQuestion', 'question_id',
            'condition'=>'answered_questions.user_id = '.Yii::app()->user->id,
            'joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN',
            ),
    );
}
```

To limit the the query to records in the parent table with no relevant ones in the child table I've used a condition in the findAll function like so-

```
            $questions = SurveyQuestion::model()->with(array(
                                            'survey_answer',
                                            'answered_questions'=>array(

                                                    'select'=>false,

                                                    'joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN',
                                                    'condition'=>'`answered_questions` . `id` is NULL'
                                                    ),))->findAll();
```

The two pieces of code return no results even when the child table is cleared.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong, in approach or execution?

Many thanks,

Nick

**Update**

As requested, here's the sql statement that is run. It's the second Join that is relevant, the first Join collects the multiple choice answers.

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`area_id` AS `t0_c1`,
`t`.`question_text` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`date_question` AS `t0_c3`,
`survey_answer`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `survey_answer`.`survey_question_id` AS
`t1_c1`, `survey_answer`.`answer_text` AS `t1_c2`, `survey_answer`.`tag_id`
AS `t1_c3` FROM `tbl_survey_questions` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN
`tbl_survey_answers` `survey_answer` ON
(`survey_answer`.`survey_question_id`=`t`.`id`)  LEFT JOIN
`tbl_answered_questions` `answered_questions` ON
(`answered_questions`.`question_id`=`t`.`id`)  WHERE
((answered_questions.user_id = 2) AND (`answered_questions` . `id` is
NULL))
```

Comment: Can you see what SQL it is actually constructing by viewing the logs? Turning on your weblog and enable profiling on your database connection. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/235/configuring-cweblogroute-for-db-profiling/

Comment: Thanks for that, I'd never turned that profiling feature on before. I've added the sql that it runs.

Comment: Do you have PHPMyAdmin installed or any other SQL interface you can actually run that against your database with visually? I can't see anything obviously wrong with that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a though after I posted the comment about visually running your query.

I think you need to put the condition for `user_id` in the `on` clause of the relation, rather than the `condition` clause. Because it's only returning parent rows where the child has `NULL` id and `user_id` of 2. This will obviously never happen. But you need it to be in the `JOIN` criteria. So it should read:

```
'answered_questions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'AnsweredQuestion', 'question_id',
    'on'=>'answered_questions.user_id = '.Yii::app()->user->id,
    'joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN',
),
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this makes a lot of sense. Hopefully I'm almost there after inputting your code, but it doesn't recognise 't.id' as a column. Is there a common rookie error in the works do you think?

Comment: I updated my example. I forgot Yii will let you *append* to the `on` condition rather than overwrite it entirely.

Comment: That's fantastic, this gives the desired behaviour. Many thanks for your help with my questions. I never thought I'd get this one solved and I've learnt a lot from you in the process. Cheers!

Comment: Good, glad you got it working. I do't know if you've looked but it's **very** worth you taking 30 minutes out of your day to skim through the main points on Yii's brilliant self-written guide. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application

Comment: I've seen it before, but I'll give it a more comprehensive run through following your recommendation. Ta